# to display a different component with each click (using hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to display a different `component` with each  `button` click.
I'm sure the `syntax` is wrong, can anyone help me? The browser doesn't load
I would love an explanation of where I went wrong

One component (instead of `HomePage`) should display on the `App component` after clicking the button. Help me to understand the right method.

Thanks!

**App.js**

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Addroom from './components/Addroom.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

function App() {

  const [flag, setFlage] = useState(false);



  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <h1>My Smart House</h1>

      <button onClick={()=>{setFlage({flag:true})}}>Addroom</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setFlage({flag:false})}}>HomePage</button>


      {setState({flag}) && (
        <div><Addroom  index={i}/></div>
      )}
      {!setState({flag}) && (
        <div><HomePage index={i}/></div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

HomePage

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            HomePage
        </div>
    )
}
```

Addroom

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function Addroom() {
    return (
        <div>
            Addroom
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```js
function App() {
  const [flag, setFlage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My Smart House</h1>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setFlage(true);
        }}
      >
        Addroom
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setFlage(false );
        }}
      >
        HomePage
      </button>
      {flag ? <Addroom /> : <HomePage /> }
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `{flag ? <Addroom /> : <HomePage /> }` this is called the [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) it is effectively a shorthand way of writing an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but as i can see it should be something like this:

```
<button onClick={()=>setFlage(true)}>Addroom</button>
<button onClick={()=>setFlage(false)}>HomePage</button>

  {flag && (
    <div><Addroom index={i}/></div>
  )}
  {!flag && (
    <div><HomePage index={i}/></div>
  )}
```

You need to call `setFlage` function with argument of `Boolean` saying `true` or `false` and it changes the `flag` variable that you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing render methods and also you should use setState for reactive rendering.( when you use state variables and once value changed render method will rebuild output so this will load your conditinal component.

> https://jsfiddle.net/khajaamin/f8hL3ugx/21/

--- HTML

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div> In Home</div>;
  }
}

class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div> In Contact</div>;
  }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      flag: !state.flag,
    }));
    console.log("hi", this.state.flag);
  }

  getSelectedComp() {
    if (this.state.flag) {
      return <Home></Home>;
    }
    return <Contact></Contact>;
  }
  render() {
    console.log("refreshed");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Click On button to see Home component loading and reclick to load back
          Contact component
        </h1
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Switch Component</button>
        {this.getSelectedComp()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to use only hooks (: