# display a component in button click (using hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm trying to display a `component` in `button` click, What do I need to change in the `syntax`?
Anyone understand where the mistake is?
The functions works but not as I need to,
I have progressed since the previous question here [display a different component with each button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984161/to-display-a-different-component-with-each-click-using-hooks)

I really want to understand the right and the simple method

Thanks!

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Addroom from './components/Addroom.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

function App() {

  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);



  return (
    <div className="App">
     
     <h1>My Smart House</h1>


      <button className="button1" onClick={()=>setFlag(!flag)}>Change Flag</button>
      {flag.toString()}

      <Addroom a={(!flag)}/>
      <HomePage h={(flag)}/>

</div>

  )
}
export default App;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function HomePage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
           <h2> HomePage {props.h}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Addroom.js

```
import React from 'react';


export default function Addroom(props) {
    return (
        <div>
           <h2> Addroom {props.a}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `The functions works but not as I need to` This is not sufficient for anyone unfamiliar with your project to understand what is going wrong. Please describe in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: I want to display a different component with each button click with a boolean value and I'm not using correctly in the hooks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With conditional operator `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

```
   {flag ? <Addroom /> : <HomePage /> }
```

If you don't need to use the `flag` inside components, skip passing as props

look at this sample
[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-b8br4)